# Sending and receiving TCP simuntainously

Tags: java, tcp

I'm trying to create a TCP client/server that sends and receives messages. My problem right now is that I can't do them both simultaneously. I'm sending a message to the server and reading it just fine, but after each received message to the server, I also want to send back a response to the client acknowledging it.

I'm sending several messages per second to the server, but when I try to re-send a message to the client, it just gets stuck, no message on either end. I can however send in either direction, client to server and server to client, but only one way.

This is the client handler for the server:

```
public TCPClientHandler(Socket client, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
    this.client = client;
    messageToClient = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
    recvFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
}
    
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        /* Read the data from the client.
         * If the message is larger than the server buffer we close the connection.
         * If the client closes connection we get exception and we catch it
         * at the end.
         */
        while (true) {
            if (recvFromClient.readLine().getBytes().length > buffer.length){
                break;
            }
            /* Receiving and printing message */
            buffer = Arrays.copyOf(recvFromClient.readLine().getBytes(),
                recvFromClient.readLine().getBytes().length);
    
            String messageFromClient = new String(buffer,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Client message: " + messageFromClient);
            messageToClient.println();
    
            /* Sending message to client */
        }
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection to client lost...");
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Connection closed on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        messageToClient.close();
        try {
            recvFromClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }            
}
```

This is the client:

```
public class TCPEchoClient {

    /*
    Args input
    1. Server Address
    2. Server Port
    3. Socket Buff Size
    4. Transfer Rate
    5. Message
     */
    public void run(String args[]){
        try {
            // Dummy values
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            int serverPort = 4950;
            int buffSize = 100;
            int transferRate = 5;
            String echoMessage = "112312451265214126531456234321";
            String receive;

            System.out.println("Connection to server on port " + serverPort);

            Socket socket = new Socket(host,serverPort);
            socket.setReceiveBufferSize(buffSize);
            System.out.println("Just connected to " + ocket.getRemoteSocketAddress());

            // Writer and Reader to write and read to/from the socket.
            PrintWriter writeToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

            BufferedReader recvFromServer = new BufferedReader(new `InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`

            if (transferRate < 1){
                writeToServer.println(echoMessage);
            }else {
                // Continuously send messages with 1 second between x amount of
                // messages, until client is aborted.
                while (true) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < transferRate; i++) {
                        writeToServer.println(echoMessage);
                        receive = new String(recvFromServer.readLine().getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        System.out.println(receive);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }

            // Close reader/writer and socket
            writeToServer.close();
            recvFromServer.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (SocketException e){
            System.out.println("Socket exception...");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TCPEchoClient client = new TCPEchoClient();
        client.run(args);
    }
}
```

I would like to read the messages that are transmitted as bytes, store them in the buffer, and THEN read the message, but so far no success.

Comment: You are calling `readLine()` once to get the length and then throwing the line away, and then calling it again. You are therefore throwing away every odd message. You are also not sending anything to the client except a line terminator.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the issue. I moved the receive part inside the client to AFTER the thread sleep.